# Is it possible to change a Shimano FC131 crankset's chainrings?

Tags: crankset

I'm going to buy a bike wtih this crank, but I want to change the bigger ring. This is one of the lower end shimano cranks -- so I am worrying that the chainrings may not be replaceable.

Thanks

Guys now I'll be needing a DIY way to change the rings cuz those gears are wayyyyyy to low for me. I need something, what about pulling off the bolts or something?.....

Comment: You'd be better off replacing the crankset. A lower end shimano one would probably be less than replacing the rings anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The lowest Shimano level crankset with replacable chainrings is in the Acera group.

In any case, most replacement chainrings cost about as much as a Tourney (or even Acera) crankset, so it doesn't make much sense to replace the chainrings on those anyway.

As mentioned in the answer to your other question, theres a very good chance your bike won't be able to clear a 48t ring if it was originally spec'd with a 42t ring.

Comment: "clear a 48t ring if it was originally spec'd with a 42t ring" --- could you please make it a bit more clearer ? Aren't there no other ways ? The specific model I'm going for unfortunately already has 14t on the smallest sprocket -- so the gear is already too low, my city has no hill - only bad roads are the problem. BTW, a lot of the people I asked for a review of this bike said it was slower than other bikes with more inferior components (so maybe it was the gear).

Comment: OK, how can I know which cranks are replaceable (by sight)? Will they have some sort of arms with tiny bolts on the side ?

Comment: By "clear a 48t ring" he means that it's likely the larger chainring will not fit as the chainstays will interfere with it. It's possible that it may fit as 48 tooth isn't huge but it's something you have to be aware of. Also, you'll need a new chain as it will need to be longer,and you'll have to check if you rear derailleur has the capacity for the extra chain slack.

Comment: The rear dera and chain wont be a problem. The bike has a more advanced model with that costs ~50% more with those specs : 
Frame: Butted Hydro formed 6061 Alloy Tubing 
Fork: 120mm XCM with Hydraulic Lockout from SR Suntour
Front Derailleur: SRAM X3
Rear Derailleur: SRAM X4
Number of Gears: 24
Shifters: SRAM X4
Chainset: Truvative FC E400
Chainrings: 42/32/22
Bottom Bracket: Truvativ BB7 Square 
Cassette: Shimano HG31
Chain: KMC Z-72
Pedals: CSL Alloy
Brakeset: SRAM BB5 Disc with G2 Clean Sweep Rotors
Brake Levers: Tektro

Comment: The frames are same with all the bikes in the series, the crank on that is definitely replaceable (a friend replaced a worn out ring). So chainstay stuff wont be a prob.